# Input field not showing up in Distance Matrix In QGIS 2.0?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, distance-matrix

I tried to perform a Distance Matrix analysis of building centroids. I have a two building centroid layers. The attributes in both the tables are `name, osm_id, perimeter and area`.

In the Distance Matrix Tool, I select this layer as input field then I have to select the unique field ID. My unique field ID is osm_id, but it does not show up in the list.

Does someone know why that could be?

I get all the other attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

osm_id is sometimes stored as a "double" field. Try copying this field in a new field with integer field type.

Answer (score 0):

The id field is not recognized when when it is long integer.

Try to chose type integer and field length less than 10.

I do not know the reason for this but at least That worked for me.